# Show splash screen instead of snapshot

Tags: ios, background, splash-screen, snapshot, default.png

My issue is with the splash screen shown when the app opens while in suspended mode.

When the app is closed and i open it, i see the Default.png splash screen, which is what i need.

But if i send it to the background and reopen it, i see a snapshot from the last screen i was in, and i want to see the splash screen.

I have even considered forcing the app to quit on when entering background, but i'd rather show a snapshot than do this.

How can i accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to application did enter background to reopen?

Comment: No, i need to show the default.png image when the app enters foreground from suspended state instead of a snapshot from the last screen before the app entered background.

Comment: duplicate of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235112/preventing-snapshot-view-of-your-app-when-coming-back-from-multi-tasking>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the image that is shown when the app starts (**Default.png**) or enters the foreground (snapshot of previous app state).

Ask yourself, how would showing a splash screen each time the app enters the foreground improve the user experience?

---

Edit: Here's a guess at a workaround:

Based on your comment below, it sounds like you're saying it would be OK if the user always came back to the main action screen. In the `applicationWillResignActive:` method, could you check what screen the users is on, and if it's not the main action screen, move back to that screen... the snapshot would be of the main action screen then (maybe!)

Comment: When the app starts i want to display the default.png. The thing is i want to show it instead of the snapshot from the previous state, also.

Comment: And the UX depends on the app. In my case, showing them the last screen is bad UX.

Comment: So if I hit the home key, read an email say, and then come back to for app, you want me to see the splash screen again? If I switch into iTunes briefly I have to see the splash screen again? If that's the only way your app makes sense you might want to rethink that part of your UI. Can you explain why it's necessary?

Comment: The app is a game that has one single action screen, the home screen. You open it, do the action and navigate through a few other screens of the app if you want to, and close it. All the other screens are contextual to the action you've just completed, so if i were to reopen the app, i'd see information that is out of context for the action i am about to do in the home screen. Regardless of what the app does and how it does it, is it possible to do what i ask?